# Trying to retrieve JSON data from website api

Tags: json, api, rest, data-extraction

Bottom line is that I'm trying to download my order history data from Lowes.com. I'm assuming there's an API endpoint that can be used but I haven't figured out the method or maybe what parameters need passed to get a successful request.

I looked at using python and scrapy but I don't believe the format of the webpages are going to be easy to parse the data.

I have found references to APIs in some of the javascript code for the website and the mobile app. Some of the relevant urls I've found:

From website -

ORDER_HISTORY_USER: '/wcs/resources/store/%0/member/%1/orderhistory/v1_0' (from function named Conduit on [www.lowescdn.com](http://www.lowescdn.com))

From mobile app:

"url": "https://lwssvcs.lowes.com/IntegrationServices/resources/mylowes/user/order/list/v1_0"

"url": "https://lwssvcs.lowes.com/IntegrationServices/resources/mylowes/user/order/instore/v1_0"

So far I've only attempted to use these links via a browser after logging into my account. Assuming I'm on the right path, what method should I use to successfully get the data?

Comment: have you consulted with Lowes.com api support? If they offer api to download order history then you do not have to figure out how to hack their service.

Comment: I tried contacting Customer support to see if there was an option to download transactions which of course was useless. Also, I found a developer website which lists some APIs but they are mostly dealing with Chatbots. I'm guessing it was put up for one of their hackathons.